# How to make a good key for a cache when given a list in python?

Tags: python, performance, recursion, caching

How do I make a good key for a cache when I want it to be a list? I don't want to just turn the list into a string because that takes too long. For example,

```
cache = {}

def recursion(lst, integer):
   if str(lst)+str(integer) in cache:
      return cache[str(lst)+str(integer)]
   ...
   cache[str(lst)+str(integer)] = answer
   return answer
```

and

```
cache = {}

def turn_list_into_str(lst):
    string = ''
    for x in lst:
        string += str(x)
    return string

def recursion(lst, integer):
    if turn_list_into_str(lst)+str(integer) in cache:
       return cache[str(lst)+str(integer)]
    ...
    cache[turn_list_into_str(lst)+str(integer)] = answer
    return answer
```

are too slow. Also, I can't just do

```
cache = {}

def recursion(lst, integer):
   if lst + [integer] in cache:
      return cache[str(lst)+str(integer)]
   ...
   cache[lst+[integer]] = answer
   return answer
```

because it doesn't work. How do I make the key to the cache without any of these?

Comment: Using `+=` in a loop is extremely suspicious and often referred to as a ["Shlemiel the painter's algorithm"](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/). To concatenate many strings into one string, use `''.join( )` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `tuple` -

```py
cache = {}
some_key = [1,2,3]
some_value = "hello_world"
cache[tuple(some_key)] = some_value
```

```py
tuple(some_key) in cache
# => True
```

```py
cache[tuple(some_key)]
# => "hello_world"
```

Better yet is if your key is already a tuple -

```
cache = {}
some_key = (1,2,3)         # <= tuple
some_value = "hello_world"
cache[some_key] = some_value
```

```py
some_key in cache
# => True
```

```py
cache[some_key]
# => "hello_world"
```